# HTML movie player not functioning on latest safari

Tags: javascript, video, safari, cross-browser, html5-video

I was interviewing with an agency this week and my interviewer was very happy with his brand new mac book. It was a bit embarr when my little movie player completely failed on the latest version of Safari. Help?

I pieced this together after searching online tutorials and a few threads on this site. Not sure where I got the code tbh. It's located at kristian.co.nz

In the future I would like to show a preview image of the video that will be playing next, any advice on how to do so would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          var videoSources = ["http://kristian.co.nz/video/Showreel2016_H264_website4.webm", "http://kristian.co.nz/video/Craftsmanintro_web.webm", "http://kristian.co.nz/video/GTA 03 shark.m4v", "http://kristian.co.nz/video/dj_intro.webm", "http://kristian.co.nz/video/Sketch.webm", "http://kristian.co.nz/video/Monkeybizz.webm"] 
          var currentIndex = 0;

    // listener function changes src
          function myNewSrc() {
              var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
              myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
              myVideo.load();
          }

    // add a listener function to the ended event
          function myAddListener(){ 
              var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
              currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % videoSources.length;
              myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
              myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
          }
      </script>
      </head>

      <body onload="myNewSrc()">

          <div id="section-title" >
              <video preload="auto" onended="myAddListener()" controls width="100%" title="" src="" poster="images/introMovie_poster.gif">
              </video>

           </div> 
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is to create another array that holds your video posters/thumbnails. Then add a listener, so that while the video is progressing it shows the thumbnail/poster for the next clip. In the example below I just use a separate div tag that says 'next clip' and shows the thumbnail of the next clip when listener function is called and accesses the next thumbnail in the array of posters/thumbnails and loads that into the img src tag.

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          var videoSources = ["http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4", "http://kristian.co.nz/video/GTA%2003%20shark.m4v", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];

          var currentIndex = 0;

          var videoThumbnails = ["https://placehold.it/150x100.jpg","https://placehold.it/150x200.jpg","https://placehold.it/150x300.jpg","https://placehold.it/150x400.jpg","https://placehold.it/150x480.jpg"];

    // listener function changes src
          function myNewSrc() {
              var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
              myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
              myVideo.load();
          }

          function myNewThumb() {
            var nextThumb = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
            nextThumbIndex = (currentIndex+1) % videoThumbnails.length;
            nextThumb.src = videoThumbnails[nextThumbIndex];
            nextThumb.load();

          }

    // add a listener function to the ended event
          function myAddListener(){
              var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
              currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % videoSources.length;
              myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
              myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
              myVideo.addEventListener('progress',myNewThumb,false);
          }
      </script>
      </head>

      <body onload="myNewSrc(),myNewThumb()">

          <div id="section-title" >
              <video preload="auto" onended="myAddListener()" controls width="480" height="360" title="" src="" poster="https://placehold.it/350x150">
              </video>


           </div>
           <div id="movie_image">
           <p>Next clip playing:</p>
           <img src="" alt="video image">
           </div>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try tonight. Does this also address the Safari problem?

Comment: Np, so after testing the issue, it's your .webm video files which are not compatible with Safari, thus I recommend converting those to something like mp4 h.264(you can use something like AnyVideoConverter to convert the files locally on your machine) if you want to provide only one source file in your video tag which is supported by Chrome, Firefox and Safari. My sample now works in Safari too since I changed the video files to ones that Safari can play.One additional to thing to note, I recommend putting something in the video `src` instead of `src='' ` , to see no errors while page loads.

Comment: Ninjaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Works great. How does the .html know that nextThumb is the img src? I can't see how you have called it.

Comment: Awesome, this line: `nextThumb = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];` grabs the first element of the page with the tag 'img'  and then this line: `nextThumb.src = videoThumbnails[nextThumbIndex];` , modifies the img src for the img tag that was grabbed